# Does the Bible ever mention atheism and where?

Tags: atheism

Not necessarily the actual word as such. Mostly people are described as chasing after other gods. What about no gods?

Comment: “You believe that there is one God. Good! Even the demons believe that—and shudder.” — https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James+2%3A19&version=NIV

Answer (score 1):

There is a **lot** of talk about Godless men, which would be someone that likely doesn't believe in God or fear God (or any gods) -- usually one or the other.

> Psalms 14:1 - The fool has said in his heart, "There is no God."
>
> Psalms 10:4 - The wicked, in the haughtiness of his countenance, does not seek Him. All his thoughts are, "There is no God."
>
> Psalm 36:1 - Transgression speaks to the ungodly within his heart; There is no fear of God before his eyes.

More from this [link](http://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/Godlessness) I found.
Also check this [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/are-there-any-atheists-in-the-bible).